# Cell Formatting - horizontalAlignment

Tags: office-js

Am trying to apply horizontal formatting on a cell, but its not working.

Rest all formatting like font color are working fine.

Host - Office 365 , Platform - Excel

Code -

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {

  var tableRange = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem(tableName).convertToRange();
  tableRange.load("values");

  return ctx.sync()
    .then(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < tableRange.values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tableRange.values[i].length; j++) {
          if (tableRange.values[i][j] == 'somecondition') {
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).values = [
              ['n']
            ];
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).format.font.color = "#ff0000";
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).horizontalAlignment = 'Center';

          }

        }
      }
    })
    .then(ctx.sync);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`horizontalAlignment` is a property of [RangeFormat](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangeformat):

```
tableRange.getCell(i, j).format.horizontalAlignment = 'Center';
```

You're complete code would therefore be:

```
Excel.run(function(ctx) {

  var tableRange = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem(tableName).convertToRange();
  tableRange.load("values");

  return ctx.sync()
    .then(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < tableRange.values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tableRange.values[i].length; j++) {
          if (tableRange.values[i][j] == 'somecondition') {
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).values = [
              ['n']
            ];
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).format.font.color = "#ff0000";
            tableRange.getCell(i, j).horizontalAlignment = 'Center';   
          }    
        }
      }
    })
    .then(ctx.sync);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```